# symfony2 does not allow me to fetch whole parameter

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 2 i have a yml file like this:

```
my_application:
  application:
      name: "Hello World"
      version: { major: 1, minor: 0, build: 4, stage: BETA }
```

If i  want to fetch `Hello World` -for example- i use this **command**:

```
echo $container->getParameter('my_application.application.name');
```

**Prints**:

```
"Hello World"
```

Now, what if i want to get the whole application? Within inside of arrays?

```
print_r($container->getParameter('my_application.application'));
```

Gives me an **error**:

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "my_application.application".
```

But it **exist**. All i want to do is fetch the whole node. As **array**.

Is it **possible**, if yes, **how**? If no, **why** again?

*- Obviously, symfony tells me that this is not a single parameter but a bag (maybe) but how can i fetch it as array? -*

Comment: yes - because it maps config into flat structure. You can see exactly how data is stored in that way: var_dump($container->parameters)

Comment: I see. Indeed it is. I checked it and yes it is much more different then i thinked. ($container->getParameterBag() do the job) I will look forward to implement this with another way or trick. Could you please post this as an aswer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes - because it maps config into flat structure. You can see exactly how data is stored in that way:

```
var_dump($container->parameters)
```